# ImportError: No module named ... on docker toolbar on windows

Tags: python, windows, docker, configuration, importerror

Im currently having an issue trying to configure a project on my windows device.

I have docker-toolbar, which is supposed to run a dockerfile with python server, but on `$ docker-compose up` im getting a massive load of `ImportError: No module named '<projects modules names>'`

As the rest of teams run it successfully on Linux I suppose there is something to do with Windows, paths maybe or idk (inb4 'why not use linux').

Of course there is an option to use VM, but I would like to use it only in finality.

Comment: DId you solved it?

Comment: Same issue here...

Comment: @2Big2BeSmall, no, as far as I remember I have just setup VM

Answer (score 0):

As stupid as it is, I still post my solution because maybe it helps some poor soul like me.

In my docker-compose.yml I had a **wrong mapping** in the `volumes`:

```
web:
   ...
   volumes:
       - .:app/wrong-subfolder
```

That's why my local code was mapped to a wrong directory and that caused `django` to not find the settings module.